# ASP.NET Core API unable to get array from from model in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I create a post api but I am unable to retrieve data from array in my api.

The model

```
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile image { get; set; }
    public String imageURL { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Langue> Langues { get; set; }
}

public class VideoLangue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public video video { get; set; }
        public int LangueId { get; set; }
        public Langue Langue { get; set; }
    }


public class Langue
    {
        public int LangueId { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the OnMOdelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Langue>()
                        .HasMany(e => e.Videos)
                        .WithMany(e => e.Langues)
                        .UsingEntity<ViodeLangue>(
                        bg => bg
                            .HasOne(bg => bg.Video)
                            .WithMany()
                            .HasForeignKey("Id"),
                        bg => bg
                            .HasOne(bg => bg.Langue)
                            .WithMany()
                            .HasForeignKey("LangueId"))
                        .ToTable("VideoLangue")
                        .HasKey(bg => new { bg.Id, bg.LangueId });
```

My controlleur is like this

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<Cours>> PostCours([FromForm] Video video)
    {
```

When i request my api and look at the value of video id and nom are ok but langues is null (count= 0 and no raw.

Request via swagger or postman give the save result (see the interface of swagger)
[image]

Request generated by swagger

```
 curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:44349/api/Cours' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'Nom=la bonne video' \
  -F 'Langues={
  "langueId": 1,
  "designation": "Français"
}' \
  -F 'Langues={
  "langueId": 3,
  "designation": "chinois"
}' \
  -F 'Id=5'
```

In visual Studio the result is

[image]

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of http request?

Comment: Hi, one exemple has been added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing form data with JSON. It either all has to be in JSON (which is what I would do) or it all has to be in form data. To add an array of values as form data, you have to use the index in square brackets (e.g. `[0]`) for each element in the array.

I think this might work (untested):

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:44349/api/Cours' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'Nom=la bonne video' \
  -F 'Langues[0].LangueId=1' \
  -F 'Langues[0].designation=Français' \
  -F 'Langues[1].LangueId=3' \
  -F 'Langues[1].designation=chinois' \
  -F 'Id=5'
```

Comment: Perfect Gabriel ! It works for me.